# Spring security's SecurityContextHolder: session or request bound?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-security

Is the Userprincipal I retrieve from `SecurityContextHolder` bound to requests or to sessions?

`UserPrincipal principal = (UserPrincipal) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();`

This is the way I access the currently logged in user. Will this invalidate if the current session is destroyed?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

It depends on how you configured it (or lets say, you can configure a different behaviour).

In a Web application you will use the [`ThreadLocalSecurityContextHolderStrategy`](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/springframework/security/spring-security-core/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-security-core-3.0.5.RELEASE-sources.jar!/org/springframework/security/core/context/ThreadLocalSecurityContextHolderStrategy.java?format=ok) which interacts with [`SecurityContextPersistenceFilter`](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/springframework/security/spring-security-web/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-security-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/security/web/context/SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.class?classDetails=ok).

The Java Doc of `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter` starts with:

> Populates the {@link
>   SecurityContextHolder} with
>   information obtained from the
>   configured {@link
>   SecurityContextRepository} prior to
>   the request and stores it back in the
>   repository once the request has
>   completed and clearing the context
>   holder. By default it uses an {@link
>   HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository}.
>   See this class for information
>   HttpSession related
>   configuration options.

*Btw: HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository is the only implementation of SecurityContextRepository (I have found in the default libs)*

It works like this:

- The [`HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository`](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/springframework/security/spring-security-web/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-security-web-3.0.5.RELEASE-sources.jar!/org/springframework/security/web/context/HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java?format=ok) uses the httpSession (Key="SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT") to store an `SecurityContext` Object.
- The `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter` is an filter that uses an `SecurityContextRepository` for example the  `HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository` to load and store `SecurityContext` Objects. If an HttpRequest passes the filter, the filter get the `SecurityContext` from the repository and put it in the SecurityContextHolder (`SecurityContextHolder#setContext`)
- The `SecurityContextHolder` has two methods `setContext` and `getContext`. Both uses a `SecurityContextHolderStrategy` to specify what exactly is done in the set- and get-Context methods. - For example the `ThreadLocalSecurityContextHolderStrategy` uses a thread local to store the context.

So in summary: The user principal (element of SecurityContext) is stored in the HTTP Session. And for each request it is put in a thread local from where you access it.