# How can I access the VaadinSession from a normal Servlet?

Tags: session, servlets, vaadin, vaadin8

I tried:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/TestServlet")
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
  @Override
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
   VaadinSession session = VaadinSession.getCurrent();
   // session is null
  }
}
```

Context: I have a few standard servlets mixed in with my normal Vaadin application. They handle for example some download or print requests. But I need a way to check for login/permissions.

Comment: I don't think you can but you can do the opposite and access the normal session from `VaadinSession` (and store what you need there).

Comment: @Oleg Thank you, I switched to `VaadinSession.getSession()` to store things like login info. From the servlet I access it through the HttpSession.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I use for solving this problem.

It requires that Spring's `RequestFilter` be installed as a servlet filter. This usually happens automatically if you're using Spring, or you can add it standalone if you're not.

```java
import com.google.common.base.Preconditions;
import com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinSession;
import com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinSessionState;

import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestAttributes;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder;

public final class VaadinSessionFinder {

    private VaadinSessionFinder() {
    }

    /**
     * Find the {@link VaadinSession} associated with the current HTTP request.
     *
     * <p>
     * The session is found by directly inspecting the current HTTP session, so this will work
     * even if the current thread is not executing within the Vaadin servlet.
     *
     * <p>
     * This method relies on Spring's {@link RequestContextHolder} to locate the current HTTP request.
     *
     * @return the {@link VaadinSession} associated with the current HTTP request, if any
     */
    public static Optional<VaadinSession> find() {

        // Get the current HTTP request
        final HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()
          .resolveReference(RequestAttributes.REFERENCE_REQUEST);

        // Find the VaadinSession in the HTTP session (this logic follows VaadinService.java)
        final String servletName = request.getHttpServletMapping().getServletName();
        final String attributeName = String.format("%s.%s", VaadinSession.class.getName(), servletName);
        return Optional.ofNullable(request.getSession(false))
          .map(session -> session.getAttribute(attributeName))
          .map(VaadinSession.class::cast);
    }

    /**
     * Invoke the given action in the context of the {@link VaadinSession} associated with the current HTTP request.
     *
     * @param action the action to perform
     * @return true if successfully dispatched, false if {@code session} is not in state {@link VaadinSessionState#OPEN}
     * @throws IllegalStateException if there is no current HTTP request or {@link VaadinSession} associated with it
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if {@code action} is null
     */
    public static boolean access(Runnable action) {
        Preconditions.checkArgument(action != null, "null action");
        final VaadinSession session = VaadinSessionFinder.find()
          .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("no VaadinSession found"));
        if (!VaadinSessionState.OPEN.equals(session.getState()))
            return false;
        session.access(action::run);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use spring security for this purposes.

Please check this answer to see how to use it
[How does spring security work on a Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148898/how-does-spring-security-work-on-a-servlet)

Comment: That's if he's using spring, which currently is unspecified. Furthermore, while links to external resources are encouraged, they can quickly become obsolete/unavailable. Thus, it would be helpful if you could quote or add a sample based on the linked content (more on [how to answer, here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer))

Comment: Yes, thank you for the link, but I am not using Spring.

Comment: Filters: Doesn't ring a bell.

Comment: Like This http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-servlets/servlet-filters.html