# Spring security custom logout null pointer exception

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-security

**What I'd like my code to do:** When user logs in I want to use default Spring Security to log him in. Then in LoginSuccessHandler I'm creating and saving to a databse a token. Using default logout, in LogoutSuccessHandler I need to delete the token from database.

**My issue:** I'm using Spring Security for login and logout. Login works correctly.  Logout used to work correctly as well, but a couple of days ago I started receiving `NullPointerException` which is caused by null Authentication in `LogoutSuccessHandler`. Also, I'd like my API to be as stateless as possible. But I'm wondering; should I disable creating session for Spring Security will login/logout still work or does it need to create some king of session? I googled a couple of questions about it, but majority of them suggested that something is wrong with configuration. I tried a couple of different ones, unfortunately none worked.

**My code:** 
`WebSecurityConfig.java`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private RESTAuthenticationEntryPoint restAuthenticationEntryPoint;
    @Autowired
    private RESTAuthenticationSuccessHandler restAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
    @Autowired
    private RESTAuthenticationFailureHandler restAuthenticationFailureHandler;
    @Autowired
    private RESTLogoutSuccessHandler restLogoutSuccessHandler;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("**/anna/**").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().permitAll();

        http
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessHandler(restLogoutSuccessHandler);

//        http.sessionManagement()
//                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER);
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }
}
```

`RESTLogoutSuccessHandler.java`

```
@Component
public class RESTLogoutSuccessHandler implements LogoutSuccessHandler {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {

        User authUser = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
        String userName = authUser.getUsername();
        com.shareabook.model.User user = userRepository.findByUserName(userName);
        user.setToken("");
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

**Stacktrace**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.shareabook.security.RESTLogoutSuccessHandler.onLogoutSuccess(RESTLogoutSuccessHandler.java:28) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_77]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_77]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_77]
```

Comment: LogoutSuccessHandler as the name implies occurs after a successful logout (so the user is no longer authenticated)

Comment: @RC, so you are suggesting that authentication should be null? If so, why majority of examples on how to write LogoutSuccessHandler has the line with checking `if(authentication != null) `? E.g. here: https://www.concretepage.com/spring-4/spring-4-security-custom-logoutsuccesshandler-example

Comment: Also, wouldn't it rather be an issue with `doFilter()`?

Comment: Which line is line 28 in `RESTLogoutSuccessHandler.java` ?

Comment: @Ralph, it's ` User authUser = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();`

Answer (score 1):

`authUser` is null that is the cause for the exeception.

`authUser` is null because the `LogoutFilter` invoke the `LogoutHandler` before it invoke the `logoutSuccessHandler.onLogoutSuccess`.

`LogoutFilter`:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

    if (requiresLogout(request, response)) {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Logging out user '" + auth
                    + "' and transferring to logout destination");
        }

        this.handler.logout(request, response, auth);

        logoutSuccessHandler.onLogoutSuccess(request, response, auth);

        return;
    }

    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

A typical `LogoutHander` implementation like `SpringContextLogoutHander` clear the authentication. But you can disable this behavior by setting `clearAuthentication` to `false`

`SecurityContextLogoutHandler`:

```
public void logout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        Authentication authentication) {
    Assert.notNull(request, "HttpServletRequest required");
    if (invalidateHttpSession) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if (session != null) {
            logger.debug("Invalidating session: " + session.getId());
            session.invalidate();
        }
    }

    if (clearAuthentication) {
        SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        context.setAuthentication(null);
    }

    SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I did change my config to `logout().clearAuthentication(false)
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessHandler(restLogoutSuccessHandler);` unfortunately it didn't help and I still have null pointer exception with the same stack trace. Do you happen to have any more ideas?

Comment: @werwwerw: Do you see the log message from line `logger.debug("Logging out user '" + auth  + "' and transferring to logout destination");` in your log? What value has `auth` in your log?

Comment: Try to set a breakpoint in the logout filter and have a look at the `auth` variable. - Maybe you spot the point where Authentication.principal become null

Comment: @Ralph: *A typical LogoutHander implementation like SpringContextLogoutHander clear the authentication.* That's right, but `auth` is a local variable, so it should be non null in `LogoutSuccessHandler`, right?

Comment: @dur: you are right - my fault. So try the debugging way. Maybe this answer gives you an other good startingpoint for debuggin: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6408377/280244

Comment: @dur, you were right. Something is breaking with my login. I can see that part of it is working - in loginSuccessHandler I'm creating a token and saving to database, but then I'm losing session. I started wondering: can I keep Spring Security login and implement my own logout controller where I'll just delete the token?

Comment: @werwwerw: Yes. AFAIK the right way is to implement a `LogoutHandler` (not a `LogoutSuccessHandler`).